# What is the typescript type for a layer in leaflet?

Tags: typescript, leaflet

What is the correct type for a layer in leaflet?

```
import {  Feature } from "geojson"

function onEachFeature(feature: Feature, layer: any) {


layer.on({

  click: () => console.log(feature.properties),
})
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use leaflet types in typescript you need to install [`@types/leaflet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet) package. Then, you can import `Layer` class from `leaflet` package:

```js
import { Feature } from "geojson"
import { Layer } from "leaflet";

function onEachFeature(feature: Feature, layer: Layer) {
  layer.on({
    click: () => console.log(feature.properties),
  })
}
```